# 401 Unauthorized Response Using Coinbase OAuth API To Send Money

Tags: node.js, http, coinbase-api

The title sums up my problems. I used the sms code for 2FA in the POST header and got a 401 Unauthorized Response. According to the [docs](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/coinbase-connect/two-factor-authentication), I'm supposed to get a 201 response. Could anyone possible guess what's missing from my POST request? Could it be because I am testing on my local machine? BTW I am using axios as my HTTP client for this Node.js project.

```
  config: {
    url: 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/1456cc98-dd71-5ae3-8e90-c04d1d87e2b8/transactions',
    method: 'post',
    data: '{"type":"send","to":"3MLCRpMDoC3BFBsaSLNimWfJFvsMVBq4Ac","amount":"0.0000018","currency":"BTC"}',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
      'CB-2FA-TOKEN': '4152880',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.1',
      'Content-Length': 95
    }, .....
```

Comment: @coinbase why is this a thing. The user has already put their 2FA code in, plus had to access their email to approve the device just so we can access their account. Now they have to 2FA again on every send? Why would anyone use coinbase oauth at this point, I'm migrating back to key, secret

Comment: yeah its a bit tedious especially for small amounts. what's key secret? i thought oauth is the only way to send on behalf of someone.

Comment: Just connecting directly with an API Key & Secret that the user can provide, skipping OAuth completely including the approval processes

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
module.exports.replaySendMoney = function replaySendMoney(smsCode){
    // in the future access token will be stored and retrieved from database
    var Client = require('coinbase').Client;
    let accessToken = '2aac7a723eb58bfaf13a9073ac7b6972dca071f14fa0abbc766e9ed9f60be596';
    let refreshToken = '17a609e13c7608ecd499a1be502da18a7096ccf2d5fe9f40fca2b87501f7c233';
    var client = new Client({'accessToken': accessToken, 'refreshToken': refreshToken});
    client.getAccount('BTC', function(err,acct){
                // REQUIRES 2FA
        acct.sendMoney({
            'to': '3MLCRpMDoC3AFBsaSLNimWfJFvsMVBq4Ac',
            'amount': '0.0000018',
            'currency': 'BTC',
            'two_factor_token' : smsCode // MISSING PARAMETER
        }, function(err, txt){
            console.log(err);
            console.log(txt);
            res.render('authPurchase', {});
        });
    });
}
```